# Python. Hint for variable

Tags: python-2.7, docstring

I'm using `PyCharm` as editor. For example, I have next function:

```
def get_instance():
    # method without doc sctring in some module
    # returns instance of MyClass
    return some_var
```

And I have second file which calls `get_instance()`:

```
var = get_instance()
```

How I can to define type of data for value? I want to use autocomplete for variable.

For example in `php` it will be like this:

```
/** @var MyClass $var */
$var = getInstance();
```

After this I will be see all methods and properties of `$var`. How to declare docstring for python variable? I know about `:type` and `:rtype`, but if I need declare type for specific variable? Can I declare a few types? What I should do?

**Note:** I can't do any changes with `get_instance()`.

Comment: have you looked at [Hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)?

Comment: Could you clarify where exactly you need or want to use docstrings?

Comment: @Rightleg in any place of code. Example: `get_docker()` return `Docker` instance(I know it). But function without docstring and I can't change it. So, I calls `var = get_docker()`.And I want to define type of `var`(that it is Docker instance).

Comment: @Olian04 it is works only with python 3. Right? One more thing: I can't change function. I need just define type of variable. See my comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the same way as description properties of class. Here example:

```
from example_module import MyClass

var = get_instance()
"""
:type var: MyClass
"""
```

Also you can use description without import like this:

```
var = get_instance()
"""
:type var: example_module.MyClass
"""
```

The **second way** is using [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code):

```
test = my()  # type: dict
```

Examples of autocomplete in Pycharm:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this via docstring, but there is a mechanism called [annotation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/). You can append whatever expression you want to parameters following a colon `:` and to the function declaration itself using an arrow `->`. For example:

```
def getInstance(param: str) -> MyClass
    return some_var
```

I have added an input parameter for purposes of illustration here. In this case `str` and `MyClass` are objects that represent the expected input and return types, respectively. They are never used in your code directly, just stashed away in an `func_annotations` attribute for end users that care about that sort of things (like editors).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how I know it's works only with python 3. Is it true? The similar way - using `:type` in docsting for each param. But sometimes convenient to specify the instance of variable(especially if you can't change docstring of function which was calls).